# Concatenate np arrays in pandas dataframe and plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = 

sample                  measurements
  1       [0.2, 0.22, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.35, 0.2]
  2       [0.2, 0.17, 0.6, 0.6, 0.54, 0.32, 0.2]
  5       [0.2, 0.39, 0.40, 0.53, 0.41, 0.3, 0.2]
  7       [0.2, 0.29, 0.46, 0.68, 0.44, 0.35, 0.2]
```

The data type in `df['measurements']` is a 1-D `np.array`. I'm trying to concatenate each `np.array` in the column "measurements" and plot it as a time series, but issue is that the samples are discontinuous, and the interval between points is not consistent due to missing data. What is the best way I can concatenate the arrays and plot them such that there is just a gap in the plot between samples 2 and 5 and 5 and 7?

Comment: What do you mean concatenating each arrays? I have no idea of which things you want to concatenate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to use the data, you can either convert the individual elements to new rows ("long form"), or create new columns ("wide form").

## Convert to new rows

This is the preferred format for seaborn.  `explode()` creates new rows from the array elements. Optionally, `groupby()` together with `cumcount()` can add a position.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample': [1, 2, 5, 7],
                   'measurements': [np.array([0.2, 0.22, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.35, 0.2]),
                                    np.array([0.2, 0.17, 0.6, 0.6, 0.54, 0.32, 0.2]),
                                    np.array([0.2, 0.39, 0.40, 0.53, 0.41, 0.3, 0.2]),
                                    np.array([0.2, 0.29, 0.46, 0.68, 0.44, 0.35, 0.2])]})
df1 = df.explode('measurements', ignore_index=True)
df1['position'] = df1.groupby('sample').cumcount() + 1
sns.lineplot(df1, x='sample', y='measurements', hue='position', palette='bright')
plt.show()
```

[image: convert lists in column to long form]

## Convert to new columns

If all arrays have the same length, each element can be converted to a new column.  This is how pandas usually prefers to organize it data. New columns are created by applying `to_list` on the original column.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample': [1, 2, 5, 7],
                   'measurements': [np.array([0.2, 0.22, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.35, 0.2]),
                                    np.array([0.2, 0.17, 0.6, 0.6, 0.54, 0.32, 0.2]),
                                    np.array([0.2, 0.39, 0.40, 0.53, 0.41, 0.3, 0.2]),
                                    np.array([0.2, 0.29, 0.46, 0.68, 0.44, 0.35, 0.2])]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['measurements'].to_list(),
                   columns=[f'measurement{i + 1}' for i in range(7)],
                   index=df['sample'])
df2.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: pandas plot from wide form dataframe]